# How to read data from Movesense directly without android adb and whiteboard cmd?

Tags: python, android, movesense

I have been working with the Movesense sensor since last week. The documentation, however, is somehow a little dirty and it took a couple of hours to get started with the sensor to read the data. Now, I am trying to get the data from the sensor with the [API](https://movesense.com/docs/esw/api_reference/). As per the documentation, there are two ways:

1. using the **whiteboard** (with `wbcmd` which is [**only be used with the programming jig**](https://movesense.com/docs/esw/tools/#wbcmd)).
2. using the **android** (with `adb` but [**without programming jig**](https://movesense.com/docs/esw/api_reference/#exchanging-data-with-the-sensor))

In both cases, there is an intermediate device (either a whiteboard or an android phone) between the sensor and the data collector e.g., the development machine. However, I am getting the sensor data from the sensor through `adb logcat` (where I need to install the [`sampleapp-debug-1-8.apk`](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-mobile-lib/downloads/) into an android phone) which is (seems to me) not a convenient approach. Now, I am trying to develop an application/service that will collect the sensor data directly from the sensor over the BLE without any intermediate device (**whiteboard** / **android**).

**Is there any way to read the data from movesense without whiteboard / android?**

> **Update 1:**

When I run [movesense-raspi-python3](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-raspi-python3), I am getting the following packet:

```
b'\x04>)\x02\x01\x00\x00\xe7\xae6\xdc\x8c\x0c\x1d\x02\x01\x04\x11\x07A\x00tpc\x88z\xb5\xccI1\x82\x9005a\x07\xff\x9f\x00\x02\x04\x12\x01\xa3'
```

**What does it mean by the above packet? What should I do to get ECG packet?**

> **Update 2:**

Petri presented in his [presentation](https://www.movesense.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/2021-04-21-Movesense-sensor-programming.pdf) (on page 17 in the `Alternative Communication Methods` section), it is possible to talk to the sensor and collect data directly without using Android and iOS. Then I run both the `python_client` and `web_client` from [gatt_sensordata_app](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/src/master/samples/gatt_sensordata_app) but both are giving following errors:

```
// web_client error:
BLE error:  NotFoundError: No Services matching UUID 34802252-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0 found in Device.
select_sensor error:  NotFoundError: No Services matching UUID 34802252-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0 found in Device.


// python_client error:
bleak.exc.BleakError: Characteristic 34800002-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0 not found!
```

I appreciate it if somebody helps me out in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? There is a sample https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/sample_applications/#gatt-sensordata
which provides a simplified BLE API that can be accessed without the MDS mobile library. The sample is here:
https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/src/master/samples/gatt_sensordata_app/

Comment: Your update 2: You'll need to update the sensor firmware to the gatt_sensordata_app sample. update packages can be found under samples/bin/